# What is the physical (i.e. non-mathematical) cause off the difference between a system of identical bosons and fermions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, pauli-exclusion-principle

From calculations in quantum mechanics, it follows that a system on identical fermions the wavefunction is anti-symmetric and these fermions can't exist in the same state. For bosons, it follows that the wavefunction is symmetric, which implies the bosons tend all to be in the same state.

But what is the **physical** mechanism behind this (instead of the mathematical cause)? In other words, what is the **physical** cause of Pauli's exclusion principle?

Comment: answer is related to Spin-Statistics theorem and the reason can only be deduced using relativistic Quantum field theory. More than that is unknown to me.

Comment: 1. What is your definition of "boson" and "fermion" if not "particle with symmetric many-body wavefunctions" and "particle with anti-symmetric many-body wavefunctions"? 2. Even once you choose a definition that makes this question non-tautological, I don't think it is meaningfully answerable. What is the "**physical**" cause of *anything* in quantum mechanics in your sense? Compare "From calculations in quantum mechanics, it follows that angular momentum is quantized. But what is the **physical** cause of this?". QM *is* inherently mathematical, do not pretend it is not.

Comment: One reason is that quantum relativistic transformations (unitary implementation of the Poincaré group) act differently on particles (fields) with either integer or half-integer spin. That different action leads to a very different behavior of particles with half-integer spin when compared to similar particles with integer spin (*e.g.* Pauli exclusion vs condensation).

Comment: @ACuriousMind-This comment is typical for you (in relation to the questions I pose). For someone who is curious, you ask very few questions. You almost only give answers! Aren't you curious what is the physics behind the Pauli principle (instead of the math)? About point 1. Fermions are particles with spin $\frac {1} {2} +n$, while for bosons we replace the $\frac {1}{2} $ by $1$. I'm sure there is a physical mechanism behind quantum mechanics. You can say that's metaphysics, but I don't believe that. I surely think it's possible to develop a theory of the **physics** behind the math.

Comment: What, I think, you really can't answer is why this physical Universe exists at all, even when you state that it has been there forever (like is said about the present conception of god).